# hide one element from the class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have dynamically appended a container:

```
<video class="col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto mp4Class" controls="controls">
  <source src="${mp4ar} "type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```js
$('.container').append(card);
```

And then some conditions

```
$(document).find(".mp4Class source").each(function(item, index) {
  if (!this.src.includes('undefined')) {
    console.log("src is:", item, index);
  } else {
    console.log("src is undefined:", item, index);
    $(".mp4Class").hide()// hides all elements, not one
   //$(this).hide() - doesnt work too
  }
});
```

I need to hide one element if `src` is `undefined` - how can I do that?

Comment: I assume from the context that you have multiple `.mp4Class` elements, which one *should* be hidden? Where is it in the HTML? How does it relate to the `source` element?

Comment: Rather than doing this in javascript, why not perform the conditional logic in whatever language you are using to build that source?  If the `mp4ar` does not exist, don't create a source for it.

Comment: What logic is building this source?  Is this a gsp/angular/react/vue?

Comment: it exists in both cases. In the first case : `<source src="https://i.forfun.com/jjzetm4r.mp4 " type="video/mp4">`. In the second case : `<source src="undefined " type="video/mp4">`

Comment: @Taplar its just simple html+jquery+ajax

Comment: Ok, so you are using a template literal for that variable?  Why not put an `if (mp4ar)` around whatever logic appends that element, so it only happens if it is defined?  The point being to not create the situation you are trying to fix, in the first place.

Comment: I have a very confusing json in api connect and therefore such conditions and checks. But of course I do not yet know how to implement it correctly, I learn from mistakes)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution you need

```js
$(document).find(".mp4Class source").each(function(item, index) {
  var $this = $(item);
  // if its not empty && doesn't contains the word undefined
  if ($this.attr('src') && $this.attr('src') !== 'undefined'){
    console.log("src is:", item, index);
  } else {
    console.log("src is undefined:", item, index);
    $this.closest(".mp4Class").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: If you can show me the context, may be I can help you.